# Question about Dually flat manifolds

Tags: information-theory, connections, flatness, fisher-information, information-geometry

I am reading "Methods of information geometry by shun-Ichi-Amari" and I got stuck in the following chapter 3 section 3.3(Dually flat spaces), let me define it first

Let $(S,g,\nabla,\nabla^*)$ is dually flat space then there exits the $\nabla-$affine coordinate system $[\theta^i]$ and $\nabla^*-$affine coordinate system $[\eta_{j}]$ such that $\langle  \; \partial_i, \partial^{j}\; \rangle=\delta_{i}^{j}$.
Let the component of the metric $g$ with respect to $[\theta^i]$ and $[\eta_{j}]$ we have $$g_{ij}=\langle  \;\partial_{i} ,\partial_{j} \; \rangle \text{ and } \langle  \;\partial^{i} ,\partial^{j} \; \rangle$$

Consider the following partial differential equation for a function $\psi:S\to\mathbb{R}$:
$$\partial_{i}\psi=\eta_{i}.........................(1)$$
we may rewrite this as $d\psi=\eta_{i}d\theta^{i}$ and a solution existes if and only if $\partial_{i}\eta_{j}=\partial_{j}\eta_{i}$

My question is how we can write $(1)$ as $d\psi=\eta_{i}d\theta^i$? and why solution exists when $\partial_{i}\eta_{i}=\partial_{j}\eta_{j}?$ Can someone explain it please? Thanks.

Comment: Are you already familiar with differential forms? The two equations are equivalent by the definition of the exterior derivative of a function. And the condition needed for there to be a solution is also covered in any introduction to differential forms.

Comment: can you give some source to read about it please.

Comment: What have you already learned about differential geometry. What textbooks have you studied?

Comment: Introduction to differential geometry by John M Lee.

Comment: I just took a look at that book and some others, and they're all a bit too dense for my taste. Here are some notes I found online. Read them very slowly, especially Chapter 1. https://www.math.purdue.edu/~arapura/preprints/diffforms.pdf

Comment: I read it but I am still getting confused here that how they have written the above partial differential equation. Can you explain it in short please. Thanks

Comment: Given a function $\psi(\theta^1, \dots, \theta^)$, its differential is the $1$-form $$ d\psi = \partial_i\psi\,dx^i. $$ Given a $1$-form $\eta_i\,d\theta^I$, the equation $$ d\psi = \eta_i\,d\theta^i $$ is equivalent to $$ \partial_i\psi\,d\theta^i = \eta_i\,d\theta^i, $$ i.e.,  $$ \partial_i\psi = \eta_i,\ 1 \le i \le n. $$
Given $\eta_i$, $1 \le i \le n$, a necessary condition for a solution to exist arises from the fact that partials commute:
\begin{align*}
0 &= \partial_j(\partial_i\psi) - \partial_i(\partial_j\psi)\\
&= \partial_j\eta_i - \partial_i\eta_j.
\end{align*}